# How do I ignore "command substitution: ignored null byte in input"?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I have this Linux shell command:

```
echo $(python3 -c 'print("Test"+"\0"+"M"*18)') | nc -u [IP] [PORT]
```

My intention is to pipe the output of the `print` statement to the netcat command. The netcat command creates a socket to some service that essentially returns an stdout of the string passed in.

The problem here is that when I try to run this command, I get this message:
`-bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input`; and my null byte `\0` gets ignored. But I don't want the null byte to be ignored.

How do I tell the system to NOT ignored my null byte and take in the input exactly as I've specified.

I have done some Google searches but honestly speaking they haven't helped much. Also, any link to some great article is much appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

Using `printf` worked.

Ordinarily passing `python3 -c 'print("Test"+"\0"+"M"*18)'` also worked.  Valued @cas explanation. I guess I might be sticking to `printf` given it's faster (though speed isn't particularly a concern in my case).

Thanks to all those who contributed :-).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Strings in bash **can not** contain a NUL byte, and that includes any output from a command substitution. Bash variables can't contain a NUL either. This can not be ignored or over-ridden (although it can be worked around in some commands, such as `printf`, by using `\0` as a representation of NUL, same as `\n` is a representation of a newline character).

You could just pipe the output of python directly into `nc`, without `echo` and command substitution (as in @CharlieWilson's answer), but even that isn't necessary.  bash's `printf` built-in can do what you want.  e.g.

```bsh
{ printf 'Test\0'; printf -- '%.0sM' {1..18}; } | nc -u [IP] [PORT]
```

This uses a group command (`{ list; }`) to first print "Test" and a NUL byte (`\0`) with printf, then uses printf again to print a zero-width string (`%.0s`) followed by an `M` 18 times.  The output of the entire group command is piped into `nc`.

This works because the `printf` format is "is re-used as necessary to consume all of the arguments" (see `help printf`), and the brace expansion `{1..18}` expands to the integers from 1 to 18, supplying eighteen arguments to a printf format string that only has one zero-width string field and a literal "M" character.  Hence, 18 M characters are output.

You can see exactly what the group command is outputting by piping it into a hex dumper like `xxd` or `hd` instead of `nc`:

```
$ { printf 'Test\0'; printf -- '%.0sM' {1..18}; } | hd
00000000  54 65 73 74 00 4d 4d 4d  4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d  |Test.MMMMMMMMMMM|
00000010  4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d                              |MMMMMMM|
00000017
```

With this, you can see that the fifth character is a NUL (`00`).

The output from python is slightly different because python's `print` automatically appends a newline character (`0a`):

```
$ python3 -c 'print("Test"+"\0"+"M"*18)' | hd
00000000  54 65 73 74 00 4d 4d 4d  4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d  |Test.MMMMMMMMMMM|
00000010  4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 0a                           |MMMMMMM.|
00000018
```

If the program you're sending this to with `nc` requires that newline, you can print that with `printf '\n'`.  or with `echo`.

```bsh
$ { printf 'Test\0'; printf -- '%.0sM' {1..18}; echo; } | hd
00000000  54 65 73 74 00 4d 4d 4d  4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d  |Test.MMMMMMMMMMM|
00000010  4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 4d 0a                           |MMMMMMM.|
00000018
```

---

FYI: for more info on group commands, see `man bash` and search for `Compound Commands`:

> `{ list; }`
>
> `list` is simply executed in the current shell environment. `list` **must** be
> terminated with a newline or semicolon.
>
> This is known as a group command.  The return status is the exit status of
> list.
>
> Note that unlike the metacharacters `(` and `)`, `{` and `}` are reserved
> words and must occur where a reserved word is permitted to be recognized.
> Since they do not cause a word break, they must be separated from `list` by
> whitespace or another shell metacharacter.

---

BTW, using printf for this will be faster than using python because it avoids the overhead of executing python and compiling the tiny python script...which would be irrelevant on anything even resembling a modern system for a one-off command, but significant if run in a loop.  e.g. on my ~ 10 year old 6-core AMD Phenom II 1090T:

```
$ time { printf 'Test\0'; printf -- '%.0sM' {1..18}; } 
TestMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
real 0m0.000s   user 0m0.000s   sys 0m0.000s

$ time python3 -c 'print("Test"+"\0"+"M"*18)' 
TestMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM

real 0m0.036s   user 0m0.028s   sys 0m0.008s
```

printf doesn't actually take 0 seconds, it takes more than that, but the amount of time is too small to be represented by my $TIMEFORMAT string.

Perl is a bit faster to start up and compile and run its tiny script than python, but you still wouldn't want to run it repeatedly in a shell loop:

```
$ time perl -e 'print "Test\0" . "M" x 18 . "\n"' 
TestMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM

real 0m0.008s   user 0m0.000s   sys 0m0.009s
```

or even faster using perl's printf:

```
$ time perl -e 'printf "Test\0%s\n", "M" x 18' 
TestMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM

real 0m0.003s   user 0m0.003s   sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: _Why_ can't this behavior be ignored or overridden?

Comment: @Vikki, Because Bash doesn't support NUL bytes in values. It internally uses C-style strings, where the NUL byte marks the end of the string, so... For command substitutions, it chooses to just remove them from the input, for other cases, the first NUL seen just terminates the string. If you do e.g. `printf -v foo 'abc\0def\n'`, you get a variable `foo` containing the string `abc`, and no error or comment.

Comment: @ilkkachu: So Bash isn't smart enough to escape NUL bytes in the input stream?

Comment: @Vikki, I don't think it would make much sense to _escape_ them, it'd require special implementation of every single string function. Starting with having `strlen()` take the escapes into account. The sensible way to allow for NULs in strings would be to save the string length separately, and not rely on a terminator character. But that would also require new implementations of all the string functions, because the standard C library uses NUL terminators. AFAIK zsh is the only shell that does support NULs in values, so it's not that Bash is especially dumb.

Comment: @ilkkachu: How does zsh do it?

Comment: @Vikki if my experience is anything to go by, zsh `echo` replaces any NUL bytes with ASCII 0x20 (space) when outputting to stdout. However, while the command substitution construct `a=$(printf "a\0a")` encounters the OP's error in bash and `printf $a | hd` gives '61 61', the same command in zsh outputs '61 00 61'. It is also interesting that in either shell, directly setting `a='a\0a'` and then `printf $a | hd` gives '61 5c 30 61', or a literal 'a\0a' with the slash and the zero.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury: OK, so why does zsh only preserve nulls when they're _not_ being echoed to stdout?

Comment: @Vikki a correction to the last comment: directly setting `a='a\0a'` and then `echo $a | hd` gives '61 5c 30 61 0a', while `printf $a | hd` gives '61 00 61`. Overall, this leads me to believe that bash is rather proactive in dealing with null characters when doing command substitution as compared to zsh.

Comment: @Vikki zsh always preserves NULs, bash always discards NULs when trying to put NULs into a variable. Interestingly, a glance at the ZSH source does not reveal some sort of special handling for naturally occurring NUL chars in strings, and the strings used in the code are standard NUL-terminated C `char*`s. Further, `echo` can output NUL chars in zsh from the escape sequence '\0' while bash `echo` doesn't interpret it. `printf` behaves similarly in both shells. The ZSH output functions must either be relying on a further sentinel value to mark string ends or having lengths stored somewhere.

Comment: It is beyond my capabilities and free time to figure out exactly how ZSH keeps track of these details. If you're that interested, you can try shooting off a Q to the devs on the ZSH IRC channel (hosted on Libera.Chat as #zsh), or maybe posting a question here.

Comment: One further thing I discovered is that even in ZSH, doing a simple `$a` after a `a='a\0a'` results in a 'a: command not found' instead of an 'aa: command not found', which would be consistent with `echo` and `printf` output. This indicates that whatever subsystem is responsible for executing commands does not handle NULs as carefully as do the builtin output functions. So the issue here boils down to where the output builtins get the info to continue past the NUL char until the actual end of the string. The length of the string is stored separately somewhere for sure.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury, `a='a\0a'` sets `a` to the four characters lowercase A, backslash, zero, lowercase A. There's no NUL bytes there. Doing `a='a\0a'` and then `echo $a` depends on if `echo` processes backslash-escapes, and that depends on the shell... `printf` always does it.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yeah I noted that shell-dependent escape sequence interpretation behaviour in one of my earlier comments.

Comment: @Vikki that really is a great question for the site. We have some pretty good zsh experts here and this is just the kind of question they tend to enjoy answering (often by writing an essay on the matter!), so please do post a question!

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury: How exactly do you propose that ZSH pass strings with embedded null bytes to execve(2)? The kernel expects to see C strings, you can't magick your way around that in userspace.

Comment: @Kevin when you put it that way, I indeed don't expect that. Brainfart.

Comment: @Kevin, on the other hand, it seems names of _functions_ in zsh can contain NULs. `$'a\0a' () { echo "hello?"; }` works fine, and then `$'a\0a'` prints `hello?`. But running `$'a\0b'` gives the error `zsh: command not found: a`. Though it does try to run the external command `a` before that, so it does make some sense. (Well, as far as allowing the NUL in function names does.)

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury: bash (builtin) `echo` by default doesn't do _any_ backslash escapes, but `echo -e 'a\0a'` does output null byte. GNU coreutils (external) `echo` is the same, perhaps not a mere coincidence.

Answer (score 17):

I believe the `echo` is the problem and is unnecessay.

Consider this line instead.

`python3 -c 'print("Test"+"\0"+"M"*18)' | nc -u [IP] [PORT]`

Comment: `echo $(somecommand)` and `$(echo somestring)` are almost always mistakes -- the `$( )` and `echo` mostly cancel each other out, except that the added complexity creates the opportunity for something to  go wrong (as in this case).

Comment: @GordonDavisson even worse, the argument to echo are IFS-split, possibly backslash-expanded, and if they begin with a dash, fun ensues, so they are pretty much always mistakes (in the Korn shell, `print -r -- $(somecommand)` may be a correct form of the first if the splitting is _deliberate_ but you cannot reliably use `--` with `echo`).